# If Database has no record, Display echo?

Tags: php, mysql

So I've made a Profile type thing, with status update, However, when there is no status's in the database, it shows blank of course, I am trying to make it so if the database is `empty`, then `echo "You have no Feed"` Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE user='$username' ORDER BY date DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($status))

if($row['user'] == '') { echo "You have no Feed"; } else {

{

echo "<table width='520'>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td width='53' height='57'  valign='top' rowspan='3'><img src='../includes/images/profile/$image' height='50px' width='50px' style='border: 1px solid #000'></td>";
echo    "<td width='411' valign='top'><font color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['sentby'] . "</font><br><font size='1px' color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['date'] . "</font></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td></td>";
echo  "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td colspan='2' valign='top'><font color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['status'] . "</font></td>";
echo   "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</p>"; 

}
}

?>
```

The way my profile works, is each person has their own profile, and if you go to someone's profile and comment on their "wall" ofcourse, it will only stay on their wall, My database is created as `'id' 'status' 'user' 'sentby'` `'user' (being the username of who's wall it was posted on)` and `'sentby' (to display who sent it)`

So basicly, I would need the `'user'` column to match if the username can't be found, and if the username isn't found then echo the message.

Comment: and `$row['user']` is coming from where exactly? Keep in mind that if your default column value is NULL, then that does not equal empty. But as posted, you seem to be putting the wagon before the horse, if that's your full code.

Comment: `$row['user']` is from the mysql_query below it.

Comment: `!$row['user']` <-- dont follow this.

Comment: I really have no clue on this one, iv'e tried everything, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql_num_rows function will return the number of rows that are fetched by the query.  This should work.

```
     $status = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE user='$username' ORDER BY date DESC");


   if(mysql_num_rows($status) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($status))

        echo "<table width='520'>";
        echo  "<tr>";
        echo    "<td width='53' height='57'  valign='top' rowspan='3'><img src='../includes/images/profile/$image' height='50px' width='50px' style='border: 1px solid #000'></td>";
        echo    "<td width='411' valign='top'><font color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['sentby'] . "</font><br><font size='1px' color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['date'] . "</font></td>";
        echo  "</tr>";
        echo  "<tr>";
        echo    "<td></td>";
        echo  "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo  "<tr>";
        echo    "<td colspan='2' valign='top'><font color='#CCCCCC'>". $row['status'] . "</font></td>";
        echo   "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</p>"; 
        }
        } else {
        echo "<p>This user has not yet updated their status.</p>";
        }
```

Comment: mysql_query is not safe and soon to be deprecated, use an ORM, or use PDO, mysqli

Comment: @datelligence It is *already* deprecated and *removed* in PHP 7.

Comment: Yes it is, However this is just for a small group of friends, however, i will learn how to use PDO and Mysqli soon, I just would like to get it online first, then i will re-code it

Comment: Ok, i Found the reason it did not work .. at the bottom of the line there is double `}` so i had to remove one, then, at the top of the line `if(mysql_num_rows($status) > 0){` that `{` needed to be moved down a line and put after `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($status))` thank you for your help! i didn't think to use mysql_num_rows!